# add_role menu pages are not visible

Tags: functions, admin-menu, capabilities, user-roles

I added a custom role this way:

```
add_role( 
'tabellenadmin',
__( 'Tabellenadministrator' ),
array(
    'activate_plugins' => true,
    'delete_others_pages' => true,
    'delete_others_posts' => true,
    'delete_pages' => true,
    'delete_plugins' => true,
    'delete_posts' => true,
    'delete_private_pages' => true,
    'delete_private_posts' => true,
    'delete_published_pages' => true,
    'delete_published_posts' => true,
    'edit_dashboard' => true,
    'edit_files' => true,
    'edit_others_pages' => true,
    'edit_others_posts' => true,
    'edit_pages' => true,
    'edit_posts' => true,
    'edit_private_pages' => true,
    'edit_private_posts' => true,
    'edit_published_pages' => true,
    'edit_published_posts' => true,
    'edit_theme_options' => true,
    'export' => true,
    'import' => true,
    'list_users' => true,
    'manage_categories' => true,
    'manage_links' => true,
    'manage_options' => true,
    'moderate_comments' => true,
    'promote_users' => true,
    'publish_pages' => true,
    'publish_posts' => true,
    'read_private_pages' => true,
    'read_private_posts' => true,
    'read' => true,
    'remove_users' => true,
    'switch_themes' => true,
    'upload_files' => true,
    'update_core' => true,
    'update_plugins' => true,
    'update_themes' => true,
    'install_plugins' => true,
    'install_themes' => true,
    'delete_themes' => true,
    'edit_plugins' => true,
    'edit_themes' => true,
    'edit_users' => true,
    'create_users' => true,
    'delete_users' => true,
    'unfiltered_html' => true
) 
);
```

As far as I know, this user should see every menu page. But only Dashboard and Users are showing. I tried to erase everything inside functions.php except for the above. No change. Do I miss something?

Comment: Where are you putting this code? Are you running it through any kind of filter?

Comment: No, I placed it inside functions.php they way you can see above.

Comment: Do you have any plugins installed? If I run this code I exactly as it is - it works as expected, I see every menu setting.

Comment: Deactivating all plugins did not help.

Comment: Maybe try wrapping it in an [init action](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/init). Is this a child themes functions file or the core themes file?

Comment: Core Theme.  Wrapping it didn't help. I almost forgot something. Don't know if it is relevant. See edit.

Comment: Forget the edit. I solved it.

Comment: What was the problem / can you supply an answer for future readers ( and mark it accepted ) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was, that I changed the capabilities AFTER I already created the role. I noticed, that if I change the roles slug, the role became duplicated. So I searched, and found

```
remove_role( 'tabellenadmin' );
```

Add that line somewhere before add_role(). You first have to remove the role, before you can change it.